# ANDROID_HOME is not set in macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos

I am setting the ANDROID_HOME path on macOS High Sierra versions 10.13.3 and 10.13.5 in bash_profile those are working fine when building the "cordova build android".

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<user-name>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user-name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user-name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

But the above ANDROID_HOME path is setting in macOS High Sierra versions 10.13.4 and 10.13.6 not working. Tried on various ways and followed the ANDROID_HOME path not set StackOverflow links but no luck. Can someone please help me.